# Jumping and moving at the same time...Help!

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

As the title says, I'm stuck with jumping and moving at the same time,

this is how I'm moving along the 'x' axis

```
-(void)collisionCheckingAndMovementRight:(ccTime)dt{

CGPoint tileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:player.position];
int tileGid = [csLayer tileGIDAt:tileCoord]; //csLayer is the layer which was created in tiled for the collision
if (tileGid) {
    NSDictionary *properties = [levelOne propertiesForGID:tileGid];
    if (properties) {

        NSString *collision = [properties valueForKey:@"Collidable"];
        if (collision && [collision compare:@"True"] == NSOrderedSame){

            //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"hit.caf"];
            return;

        }

    }

}

player.position = ccp(player.position.x +100*dt, player.position.y);
```

i want to try and do a jump that goes with the movement i have at the moment for the x axis.... help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the actions examples in cocos2d.  the CCBezierTo action comes to mind for a good way of animating a jump.